# JavaScript - Is there a simple way to get the values for every occurrence of a specific key in nested JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON structure similar to this:

```
[
  {
    cells: [
     { id: "1", cellType: 3, widget: { id: 1, description: "myDesc"} },
     { id: "2", cellType: 4, widget: { id: 2, description: "myDesc2"} }
    ]
  },
  {
    cells: [
      { id: "3", cellType: 5, widget: { id: 3, description: "myDesc3"} }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

How do I get the value of every `widget` into a separate array using EcmaScript (or anything that's available in Angular 2+), and without using a library (including JQuery)? I need a final array like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    description: "myDesc"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "myDesc2"
  },
  ... 
]
```

**Update**

(and thanks to @Felix Kling for the 1st part) - I found I can get all of the widgets with this:

```
JSON.parse(json)[0].forEach( c => c.cells.forEach( c2 => console.log(c2.widget)));
```

Comment: `[].concat(...JSON.parse(json).map(obj => obj.cells.map(cell => cell.widget)))`.

Comment: `myDesc3 ` will not be a part of this array?

Comment: sorry @void I've clarified the question - all widget objects should be part of the final array

Comment: While there are more concise ways using `reduce`, couldn't you just write nested loops?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let input = [
  {
    cells: [
     { id: "1", cellType: 3, widget: { id: 1, description: "myDesc"} },
     { id: "1", cellType: 4, widget: { id: 2, description: "myDesc2"} }
    ]
  },
  {
    cells: [
      { id: "3", cellType: 5, widget: { id: 3, description: "myDesc3"} }
    ]
  },
];

let result = input.reduce((result, current) => {
  return result.concat(current.cells.map(x => x.widget));
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.map()` and `.concat()` to get the desired result:

```js
let data = [{
  cells: [
    { id: "1", cellType: 3, widget: { id: 1, description: "myDesc"} },
    { id: "1", cellType: 4, widget: { id: 2, description: "myDesc2"} }
  ]}, {
  cells: [
      { id: "3", cellType: 5, widget: { id: 3, description: "myDesc3"} }
  ]
}];

let result = [].concat(...data.map(({cells}) => cells.map(({widget}) => widget)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```